# What is the packet format of a IPV6 VRRPv3 packet?

Tags: ipv6, vrrp

Can some one please share the wireshark packet capture for VRRPv3 for ipv6 packets

Comment: The VRRP packet is the same for IPv6 as for IPv4, except that it is encapsulated in IPv6 instead of IPv4.

Comment: Look what I found with 2 seconds of Google searching: https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/it/doc/EDOC1000178318/6e22bde4/vrrpv2-and-vrrpv3-advertisement-packets#fig_dc_fd_vrrp_000502

Comment: Thanks, but i am in need of a packet capture for IPv6 VRRP, to test .Can you help.

Comment: If you need something like that, then, unfortunately, your question is off-topic here. You will need to mirror on the switch between the routers for the VLAN(s) for which you want to capture.

Answer (score 2):

The VRRPv3 packet format is exactly the same for IPv4 and IPv6. The VRRP packet is encapsulated in either IPv4 or IPv6, so the IP header will vary per version, but the rest of the packet is the same.

> **5.1. VRRP Packet Format**
>
> This section defines the format of the VRRP packet and the relevant
> fields in the IP header.
>
> ```
>   0                   1                   2                   3
>   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
>  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>  |                    IPv4 Fields or IPv6 Fields                 |
> ...                                                             ...
>  |                                                               |
>  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>  |Version| Type  | Virtual Rtr ID|   Priority    |Count IPvX Addr|
>  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>  |(rsvd) |     Max Adver Int     |          Checksum             |
>  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>  |                                                               |
>  +                                                               +
>  |                       IPvX Address(es)                        |
>  +                                                               +
>  +                                                               +
>  +                                                               +
>  +                                                               +
>  |                                                               |
>  +                                                               +
>  |                                                               |
>  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> ```

This is all detailed in *[RFC 5798,  Virtual Router Redundancy Protocol (VRRP) Version 3 for IPv4 and IPv6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5798)*.